# I'm using an insertSort method but for some reason when outputting my array one of the inserts overwrites the other input in the array

Tags: java

I have two classes plus main.

1. Movie
2. MovieArray

Movie contains the info() method which prints out the "inserts" in main.

Anyways, when running the code, my third inserted elements outputs twice, overwriting the other option.

output: https://gyazo.com/7374a4546b3f8980f148c995e7ffa833

Movie Class

```java
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package movieap;

/**
 *
 * @author T
 */
public class Movie {

    String Movie;
    int rating;

    Movie(String m, int r){
        this.Movie = m;
        this.rating = r;
    }

    public void info(){
        System.out.println("The movie: " + this.Movie + ", is rated a: " + this.rating);
    }


}
```

MovieArray

```java
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package movieap;

/**
 *
 * @author T
 */
public class MovieArray {

    public Movie[] arrMovie;
    public int nElems = 0;

    MovieArray(int size) {
        arrMovie = new Movie[size];
        nElems = 0;
    }

    public void insert(String m, int rating) {
        arrMovie[nElems] = new Movie(m, rating);
        nElems++;
    }

    public void insertSort() {
        int in, out;

        for (out = 1; out < nElems; out++) {

            Movie temp = arrMovie[out];
            in = out;
            int j = in - 1;
            while (in > 1 && arrMovie[j].Movie.compareToIgnoreCase(temp.Movie) >= 0) {
                arrMovie[in] = arrMovie[j];
                --in;
            }
            arrMovie[in] = temp;

        }

    }

    public void display() {
        for (int i = 0; i < nElems; i++) {
            System.out.println(i + 1 + " - ");
            arrMovie[i].info();
        }
        }
}
```

MovieApp (Main)

```java
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package movieap;

/**
 *
 * @author T
 */
public class MovieAp {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here

        MovieArray arrMovie;
        arrMovie = new MovieArray(5);

        arrMovie.insert("Avengers", 3);
        arrMovie.insert("eello", 3);
        arrMovie.insert("zes", 6);
        arrMovie.insert("co", 4);

        System.out.println("The following movies are rated alphabetically");
        arrMovie.insertSort();
        arrMovie.display();
    }

}
```

Output should order the four options alphabetically, which it does do, but it has the fourth element overwrite the third...

Comment: Too much variables `in` and `j`. You have to clarify the usage of each index.

Answer (score 0):

Your sort is still incorrect.  To see this, add the movies in a different order. 
Here is one possible algorithm, based on this article on [Insertion Sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort)

```java
   public void insertSort() {
      int in, out;

      for (out = 1; out < nElems; out++) {
         in = out;
         while (in > 0 && arrMovie[in - 1].Movie.compareToIgnoreCase(
               arrMovie[in].Movie) >= 0) {
            Movie temp = arrMovie[in];
            arrMovie[in] = arrMovie[in - 1];
            arrMovie[in - 1] = temp;
            --in;
         }
      }
    }
```

As you will see in the article, other algorithms offer some performance improvement.

Comment: I did but I have less than 15 rep so nothing happens. @WJS

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

```
public void insertSort() {
    int in, out;

    for (out = 1; out < nElems; out++) {

        Movie temp = arrMovie[out];
        in = out;
        //got rid of this --->   int j = in - 1;
        while (in > 1 && arrMovie[in - 1].Movie.compareToIgnoreCase(temp.Movie) >= 0) {
            arrMovie[in] = arrMovie[in - 1];
            --in;
        }
        arrMovie[in] = temp;

    }

}
```

**Reasoning**

In order for Insertion sort to work, you must compare the `arrMovie[out]` value to all of the values before it, until it gets to a value that is smaller than itself. In your scenario `j` remained constant, so you were comparing the same two movies repeatedly. If you need a good visual on insertion sort, visit https://visualgo.net/bn/sorting.

You were just making the same comparison rather than continuing moving to the left and checking the other smaller values, and it was preventing your code from finishing properly.